# Missing argument for parameter error in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am exploring Swift and trying to write a function that compares two Rank values by comparing their raw values. But I get the error: missing argument for parameter 'rawValue' in call card().compareValue(card.Ace, card.King)

Any ideas?

```
enum card : Int {
    case Ace = 1
    case Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten
    case King, Queen, Jack

    func cardValue() -> String {
        switch self {
        case .Ace:
            return "Ace"

        case .King:
            return "King"

        case .Queen:
            return "Queen"

        case .Jack:
            return "Jack"

        default:
            return String(self.rawValue)
        }
    }

    func compareValue(val1: card, val2: card) -> String {
        if val1.rawValue > val2.rawValue {
            return "\(val1) is greater than \(val2)"
        } else {
            return "\(val1) is not greater than \(val2)"
        }
    }
}

card().compareValue(card.Ace, card.King) // error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the construction of the `card()` object, the target of the invocation:

```
card(). // and so on
```

You are trying to construct an `enum` without specifying its raw value. You can fix it by supplying it, like this

```
card(rawValue:0). // <<=== This is not a good fix!
```

but that is not a good fix. Instead, you should make `compareValue` a `static` or a free-standing function:

```
static func compareValue(val1: card, _ val2: card) -> String
//                                   ^
... // Note the underscore ----------+
card.compareValue(card.Ace, card.King) // Works
```

Comment: i'm new to the language but is it because i dont have a init()?

Comment: @jebmarcus `enum`s with default values (also known as "raw values") always have an `init` which takes a single parameter called `rawValue`. You made such an `enum` because you used `: Int` in its declaration. That's why the compiler inserted `init(rawValue:Int)` for you. When you try constructing `card()` with no raw value, the compiler found no corresponding `init`, and reported an error.

Comment: so should i make a new init that defaults to a value when no raw value is found? will that solve it

Comment: also why does the underscore fix it?

Comment: @jebmarcus It's not the underscore that fixes it, it's the `static` in front of the `func` and no parentheses after `card` in the call. I added an underscore so that your call could stay unchanged. Without an underscore you would need to call with a parameter name: `card.compareValue(card.Ace, val2:card.King)`.

Comment: @jebmarcus As far as adding an `init` with no params goes, this would be just as bad a solution as passing `0` for the raw value. `enum` should not have a default constructor. Whoever is constructing it must know what `enum` value he is after.

Comment: instead of fixing this solution, how would you solve this problem?

Comment: @jebmarcus That's exactly how I would solve this problem - with a `static` function inside the `enum`. If I were to provide real comparison (as opposed to comparison returning a `string`) I would provide an implementation of `operator <` instead, and implemented a comparison protocol. I would also rename this class, because your `enum` defines a card rank, not a card (you need add a suit to make it a card).